# Can't compile my project in Overleaf because of compilation timeout

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, compiling, overleaf, externalize

I am trying to compile a file with a lot of Tikz images (about 90) with pdfLaTex and this is always giving me a compilation timeout error. I tried to externalize the images with the commands:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
```

but this is always giving me the error:

```
dfTeX error: pdflatex (file /compile/tikz/output-figure33.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed

==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

(This error is not necessarily linked to the figure 33, it changes)

There is no error in the code as this used to work well until the number of pictures grew. Sometimes I manage to get the project started commenting a lot of the pictures, compiling and then progressively uncommenting some until I get to the end, but this takes a lot of time and is very uncomfortable.

Comment: Is it definitely building the external files?  If it's truly timing out and there's no way to speed that up, you may need to pay for a premium account (I believe that gives you more time) or install TeX locally.  Installing TeXLive isn't too bad, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Teepeemm When I compile it normally it's giving me a compilation timeout, if I try to externalize the pictures (that should be the solution in order to compile more rapidly) I'm receiving the error described in the question. In this last case, if I look at the log there are some files produced but the compiler will just block because of the error.

Comment: if you externalise the first run will take even longer and time out but as long as it has made some of the images you should be able to re-run and eventually it will make them all, or (simpler really) make the tikz images as separate standalone projects then justupload the pdf to your main project and include them as pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it should do so, but when the error I reported comes out (and it always does) it won't compile anymore

Comment: delete the pdf that errors; it may have timed out while being made and left it corrupt, or as I say make the figures in separate projects

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) If you send us your project's URL via email at support@overleaf.com, we can take a look to see if there's anything that can be further optimized, or if your project has simply grown too large to compile on the free plan.